# On Kubuntu 14.04, Muon doesn't work after update and upgrade via terminal

Tags: 14.04, updates, software-center, kubuntu, muon-package-manager

I ran:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

on my terminal.  After that, neither the "muon update manager" nor the "muon software center" work, when run, they both give an error:

**Initialization Error**

```
The Package system could not be initialized, your configuration may be broken.
```

**Details**

```
Encountered a section with no package: header
```

I tried restarting the computer, update, upgrade a few times continually, and didn't help.  Then I tried:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

on a terminal and got a set of these errors:

**Reading package lists... Error!**

```
**E:** Encountered a section with no Package: header

**E:** Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_main_i18n_Translation-en

**E:** The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Then I tried:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a    
sudo apt-get install -f   
sudo apt-get update    
sudo apt-get install muon --reinstall
```

but received the same errors quoted above for the lines 2 and 4

Does anyone know why I am having all of these problems or what I have done wrong?

Comment: I don't know Ubuntu that much to understand if they're both the same thing. And I don't dare do the solution named in the post you linked, in fear of extra damage. Please give me an explicit answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Terminal and enter:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
```

Then DON'T `sudo apt-get update`

Update via muon, or else you might fall into the same problem again.

Solved my problem completely.